# CPPUnit ASSERT for C function which returns multiple parameters

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, assert, cppunit

I have to use CPPUnit in my project which includes both C++ and C codes. How do I CPPUNIT_ASSERT the following function for unit testing:

```
void readData(char* locationOfData,int* sizeT, int* sizeW,double* values);
```

INPUT: locationOfData - path to data file

OUTPUTS: sizeT, sizeW, values(array)

For simple functions like finding minimum of three numbers, we can use:

```
CPPUNIT_ASSERT(1==minValue(2,3,1));
```

How do I unit test the function readData above?

Comment: Use variables to store the return values and assert on them?

Comment: Yes, I exactly followed that approach.                                                              
    char *locationOfData = "data.dat";
    int sizeT = 0;
    int sizeW = 0;
    double *values =(double*)calloc(sizeof(double),MAXBIG_DYNAMIC_MEMORY_THRESHOLD_FOR_UNSPECIFIED_SIZE);
    if(sampledValues==NULL){
        (defaultLogStatus==1 ? logToDefaultFile("testReadData: COULD NOT ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR values",1):0);
        exit(0);
    }
   readData(locationOfData,&sizeT,&sizeW,values);
   CPPUNIT_ASSERT(40000==sizeT);
   CPPUNIT_ASSERT(8000==sizew);

Comment: But how do I assert on the array values which has a length of 40000?

Comment: Unless you are dealing with critical systems, in which CPPUnit is maybe not the best choice, you should not unit test on such amount of data... Unit tests should be small and cover the required part of your software, these are not integration test.

Comment: Thanks. Basically, I am dealing with ML algorithms here which involve huge data sets. And perhaps there is no scope for breaking down the readData function further into smaller units. There are no function calls inside it. Maybe I will have to restructure the code inside readData into smaller units to make it unit test ready but I am not sure if that approach will be right considering the limited time and resources I have.